Values in variables resetting once stored
When I run this indicator, once value is above A, has risen above A should permanently be set to True, but it is again changing back to false as the value drops below A, how to overcome this. once set to true, i do not want the value to change
indicator("Test Persistent Variables", overlay=true)

// Persistent Variables
var float A = na
var float B = na
var label status_label = na
var bool has_dropped_below_D = false
var bool has_risen_above_A = false

    A := 2715
    B := 2714.5



// Logic
if close > A
    has_risen_above_A := true
   

if close < B
    has_dropped_below_D := true  // Update flag


if na(status_label)
    status_label := label.new(x=bar_index, y=high, text="Initializing...", style=label.style_label_down, color=color.blue)

label.set_xy(status_label, bar_index, high)
label.set_text(
    status_label,
    "N: " + str.tostring(N) + 
    "\nAbove A: " + str.tostring(has_risen_above_A) + 
    "\nBelow B: " + str.tostring(has_dropped_below_D)
)


